# PATCH request using Jersey Client

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I want to execute a PATCH request supported by our server for testing using Jersey client. My code is as below, but I get `com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP method PATCH doesn't support output` exception. Can someone let me know whats wrong with the code below?

```
String complete_url = "http://localhost:8080/api/request";
String request = "[{\"op\":\"add\", \"path\":\"/name\", \"value\":\"Hello\"}]";
DefaultClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    config.getProperties().put(URLConnectionClientHandler.PROPERTY_HTTP_URL_CONNECTION_SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource resource = client.resource(complete_url);
ClientResponse response = resource.header("Authorization", "Basic xyzabCDef")
 .type(new MediaType("application", "json-patch+json"))
 .method("PATCH", ClientResponse.class, request);
```

Here is the full exception,

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP method PATCH doesn't support output
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.method(WebResource.java:634)
    at com.acceptance.common.PatchTest.patch(PatchTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP method PATCH doesn't support output
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1021)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler$1$1.getOutputStream(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:238)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:89)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:272)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:276)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:122)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:212)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:236)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:300)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:217)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
```

Comment: Any way to suppress the warnings or avoid them altogether? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67682124/16022919

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug in the current JDK implementation which has been fixed in the JDK8 implementation.Checkout this link for details https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7157360.
There is a way to hack around this but Jersey team decided not to fix it https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/1639

2 solutions which I can think of

1. use Apache Http Client which supports HttpPatch method
2. use Jersey Client PostReplaceFilter but the Container code has to be modified and include X-HTTP-Method-Override header with value as PATCH while
   making a post request. Refer to http://zcox.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/override-the-http-request-method-in-jersey/
   ]

Comment: I migrated to Jersey 2.1 (2.35), adding this property on client creation works fine jerseyClient.property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);, the call is: Response response = invocationBuilder.method("PATCH", Entity.entity(jsonRequestString, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));

Answer (score 57):

FYI - just in case anyone runs into this in Jersey 2, see the [HttpUrlConnectorProvider documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest3x/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/HttpUrlConnectorProvider.html)

and use the SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND property as follows:

```
Client jerseyClient = ClientBuilder.newClient()
        .property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true)
        ... etc ...
```

Took me forever to find this - figured I could help short circuit the learning curve for others.

Comment: it worked ;)  anyway, PATCH is part of the HTTP standard since 2010 (rfc 5789)... quite weird that in 2017 still Jersey does not support it natively

Comment: It solved the error but I am getting unauthorized 401 using a client that works properly for get calls that needs authorization as well, and thoughs?

Answer (score 15):

If you're using `HttpsUrlConnection` (note the **'s'**) - then setting the `HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND` won't work. Keep reading for a detailed solution.

In my case, setting `HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND`property caused a `NoSuchFieldException` since my `HttpUrlConnection` instance was actually of type: `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl` and it's super: `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` (which inherits from `HttpUrlConnection`).

So when Jackson code try to get the method field from my connection instance super (instance of `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`) here:

```
/**
 * Workaround for a bug in {@code HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(String)}
 * The implementation of Sun/Oracle is throwing a {@code ProtocolException}
 * when the method is other than the HTTP/1.1 default methods. So to use {@code PROPFIND}
 * and others, we must apply this workaround.
 *
 * See issue http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-639
 */
private static void setRequestMethodViaJreBugWorkaround(final HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection, final String method) {
    try {
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(method); // Check whether we are running on a buggy JRE
    } catch (final ProtocolException pe) {
        try {
            final Class<?> httpURLConnectionClass = httpURLConnection.getClass();
            AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object run() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
                    final Field methodField = httpURLConnectionClass.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("method");
                    methodField.setAccessible(true);
                    methodField.set(httpURLConnection, method);
                    return null;
                }
            });
        } catch (final PrivilegedActionException e) {
            final Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
                throw (RuntimeException) cause;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(cause);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We get a `NoSuchFieldException` stating that a field named `method` doesn't exist (since getDeclaredFields() brings all the fields, regardless of their accessibility but only for the current class, not any base classes that the current class might be inheriting from).

So I looked into Java's HttpUrlConnection code and saw that the allowed methods are specified by an **private static** String[]:

```
 /* Adding PATCH to the valid HTTP methods */
 private static final String[] methods = {
     "GET", "POST", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE", "TRACE"
 };
```

The solution was to change this methods array using reflection:

```
 try {
         Field methodsField = HttpURLConnection.class.getDeclaredField("methods");
         methodsField.setAccessible(true);
         // get the methods field modifiers
         Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
         // bypass the "private" modifier 
         modifiersField.setAccessible(true);

         // remove the "final" modifier
         modifiersField.setInt(methodsField, methodsField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

         /* valid HTTP methods */
         String[] methods = {
                    "GET", "POST", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE", "TRACE", "PATCH"
         };
         // set the new methods - including patch
         methodsField.set(null, methods);

     } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Since methods field is static, changing its value works for any concrete instance that is extending `HttpUrlConnection` including `HttpsUrlConnection`.

Side note: I would prefer Java to add the PATCH method to the JDK or from Jackson to perform the field look up through the entire hierarchy in their workaround.

Anyway, I hope this solution will save you some time.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this! I wouldn't have figured it out in years, and I told a coworker I could implement the feature having seen others do it, but not realizing a different class in between would screw it all up for me!

Comment: Thanks for the above solution using the java reflection, It works for me.

Comment: Very advanced answer!

Answer (score 3):

Easy answer would be :

**Dependencies**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
     <version>2.27</version>
 </dependency>
```

Need to add `HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND` =`true`

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig).property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);
```

**Request**

```
client.target("base_url").path("end_point").request().headers("your_headers")
       .build("PATCH", Entity.entity("body_you_want_to_pass", "content-type"))
       .invoke();
```

Comment: hmm, that gives me an error "Not supported Method". But the same "PATCH" method works from javascript client

Comment: Are you using same dependencies as i mentioned ?

Comment: Yes, I used the above dependencies with same version.