# how to use PATCH method with Jersey Invocation Builder?

Tags: patch, jersey-client

```
WebTarget webTarget = httpClient.target(url);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(HttpUtils.AUTHORISATION_HEADER_NAME, "Bearer " + theAccessToken);
response = invocationBuilder.put(Entity.json(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload)));
```

httpClient is of type `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` and gets injected.

invocatioBuilder implements `javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder`, but is defined in package `org.glassfish.jersey.client`

invocationBuilder.put, invocationBuilder.post, invocationBuilder.get all exist and work, but here is no invocationBuilder.patch - it's missing.

Any suggestions on how to patch?

==== UPDATE ====

After some googling, it seems that jersey client has no support for patch. As all our apps API calls are made using jersey client, this is a bit of a problem.  I assume Ill need to find an alternative library, method and code to call patch, but it needs to support OATH 2.0 also.  Any ideas if such a library exists, and, ideally has some examples?

FYI, using Java 1.8.0_131-b11

Comment: `method("PATCH")`

Comment: Hi, in my IDE, I only have post, get and put, no patch.

Comment: [`method()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#method-java.lang.String-). https://stackoverflow.com/a/26341128/2587435

Comment: Nice, I didnt know method() was a direct substitue for put(), post() etc.  I tried it, and now get "javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH" on the line with "response = invocationBuilder.method("PATCH", Entity.json(...)".  Googling this error, some suggest "Client jerseyClient = ClientBuilder.newClient()
            .property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true)" but I dont have a Client object, only a WebTarget and a Invocation.Builder object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to @Paul Samsotha, the working solution is this:

```
WebTarget webTarget = httpClient.target(url);
webTarget.property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(HttpUtils.AUTHORISATION_HEADER_NAME, "Bearer " + theAccessToken);
response = invocationBuilder.method(HttpMethod.PATCH, Entity.json(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload)));
```

Comment: What version of jersey-client are you using ?

Comment: @alex found this to work with `<jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>`

Answer (score 0):

I found @Paul Samsotha, @John Little Accepted Answer to be correct.

If you don't find `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` to be directly injectable, a Bean method similar to this (if you have a Bean that `extends extends Consumer<ClientBuilder>`) may further help to access it:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;

@Bean
public Consumer<ClientBuilder> patchOverrideEnhancer() {
    return (client) -> {
        client.property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);
    };
}
```