# How to use PATCH method with Jersey client (2.25.1)?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I need to call a rest end point with the PATCH method but I can not find PATCH method in jersey client. Can anyone please help me how can I call the PATCH method?
I am using java 8.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Searching for your question here on Stack Overflow turns up quite a few answers; for example [how to use PATCH method with Jersey Invocation Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55778145/5698098). Please clarify how these existing Q/A do not answer your question. – As a new contributor you may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as well as [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

`@PATCH` is available from JAX-RS v2.1. Jersey in version 2.26 have that implemented.

In a version prior JAX-RS v2.1, common way of doing that is:

```
@HttpMethod("PATCH")
public void pathcMetod(...){}
```