# PATCH request for HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, http, https

I'm trying to do a PATCH in Java, and I tried this solution [PATCH request using Jersey Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355235/patch-request-using-jersey-client)

However, I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final java.lang.String[] java.net.HttpURLConnection.methods accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @6b29883d
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171)
at main.Methods.modifyPATCH(Methods.java:163)
at main.Methods.connectPATCHtoken(Methods.java:144)
at main.GetServerProperties.locator(GetServerProperties.java:91)
at swing.MainWindow$8.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:177)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

This is the code that I added:

```
    public static void modifyPATCH(final HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection, final String method) {
    try {
         Field methodsField = HttpURLConnection.class.getDeclaredField("methods");
         methodsField.setAccessible(true);
         // get the methods field modifiers
         Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
         // bypass the "private" modifier 
         modifiersField.setAccessible(true);

         // remove the "final" modifier
         modifiersField.setInt(methodsField, methodsField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

         // valid HTTP methods 
         String[] methods = {
                    "GET", "POST", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE", "TRACE", "PATCH"
         };
         // set the new methods - including patch
         methodsField.set(null, methods);

     } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

And I'm calling it from this method:

```
public static void connectPATCHtoken(URL url, String token) {
    
    try {
        
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
        modifyPATCH(connection, "PATCH");
        connection.setRequestMethod("PATCH");   
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        String oauth = "OAuth " + token;
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", oauth);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        setConnection(connection);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I updated the JDK to version 17 and it didn't help.

Answer (score 7):

Since Java 17 reflections throws exceptions before 17 it was only a warning.

Set these command line options to allow the reflection

```
 --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
```